# Finding xy position of a bitmap

Tags: c, bitmap, position, pixel

I wrote a function in order to get the position of the requested pixel position (`x250 y230` - central of the entire picture - `x500 y460`). The problem is that the function returns the position with 17 pixels difference more on up and 12 pixels difference more on right. What am i missing.. the padd? How can i use this function properly?

```
size_t find (FILE* fp, dword xp, dword yp)
{
    int i;
    int pointer = (sizeof(DIB)+sizeof(BMP)+2)+(250*3);

    for(i=0; i<460; i++)
    {
        fseek(fp, pointer+(i*pointer), SEEK_SET);
    }
     return ftell(fp);
}
```

Comment: I think you might indeed be missing the padding bytes in your calculations. I did once and my bitmaps were '*italics*' when I tried to draw them.

Comment: Yes but the qestion is how can I implement the paddings in this func.

Comment: You have to find the pixel table inside the bitmap file (from the bitmap header, more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_file_format#Bitmap_file_header)) and look through it using the formula for row-size [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_file_format#Pixel_storage) multiplied by your row number `yp`, adding your column-number `xp` times the size of one pixel.

Comment: I.. just couldn't understand that.

Comment: Alright don't worry I'll make it in an answer and try to be more explicit and clear.

Comment: Thanks. And i hope you get what i want, because im not native speaking. I just want to use that function to return the x/y of the specified px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comments, you are indeed missing the padding, but not only that.

A [bitmap file is composed of multi parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_file_format): Headers, a color map, and a Pixel map (mainly).

From what I understand of your question, you need your function to return the offset address in the file fp (considered to be a bitmap file) of the pixel that would be at position `xp ; yp`. To do that you need at least three things:

- The offset of the pixel map's begginning : you will find it by reading the last 4 bytes (a `dword`) of the [Bitmap file header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_file_format#Bitmap_file_header), you can get it by reading at offset 10 in your file.
- The pixel-per-row (or image width) number : you will find it in the BITMAPINFOHEADER
- The bit-per-pixel number : you will find it in the BITMAPINFOHEADER

When you have this, the address of your pixel in the file is :

```
rowSizeInBytes = (((bitPerPixel * imageWidth + 31) * 4) / 32);
pixAddress = pixelMapStartAddress + rowSizeInBytes * yp + ((xp * bitPerPixel) / 8);
```

Comment: Seems to work on height but the pixel i putted on that adress is almost at the end of the width of the picture.

Comment: the pixel have been seen in 230x229 when i use:
`fseek(fp, find(fp, 1, 230), SEEK_SET);` and put a pixel in that adress.

Comment: What do you mean "the pixel have been seen" ?

Comment: The output pixel. Its x had to be at the middle.
`byte pixel[] = {255, 255, 255};`
`fseek(fp, find(250, 230), SEEK_SET);`
`fwrite(&pixel, 1, sizeof(pixel), fp);` thats the function i use to put the pixel in the middle.

Comment: Ok, and then you look at the bitmap with some external program I presume? Are you sure you've got the correct variables from the headers? You could try to print them and compare them to what an external program could give you?

Comment: Im opening the bmp with Windows Viewer and Paint.
The variables are correct:
 `word bpx = (3*8);`
 `dword offset = (2+sizeof(BMP)+sizeof(DIB));`
 `dword w = 500;` then i use them exactly like you said. and the function `find()` returns the PixAdress.

Comment: Why are you declaring bpx and offset, and not using the actual file header? For example with a `read(fp, &header, sizeof(header));`

Comment: Because it doesn't matter. bpx are the bits per pixel and the offset is where the pixel aray is located.

Comment: Yes and that's why it matters! How can you expect to have the correct value **in the file** if you do not take them **from the file**? The bpx and offset are not trivial, or else they would not be written in the header.

Comment: How come don't take them from the file.. bpx never change as well as the offset.. why should i take them if i already know their value

Comment: What is the use of your function if it is only working for this specific file?

Comment: by removing 31 from the rowsize formule.. the func returns the correct x.

Comment: Thanks. But it makes no sense tho. The only thing i didn't understood from the formule is that 31 anyway. What is it..

Comment: I think it was used to do a `Math.Ceil()` equivalent, took it from the wikipedia page.

Comment: @Eregrith: please look at this formula again. That last edit *removes* an important point: **adjusting for padding**. The semi-magic adjustment `+31` is to be followed by `/32` and so will **round upwards** to the next DWORD. Multiplying by 4 gives a correct offset in bytes. Most likely, there is another error in the OPs code which makes it "not work" with (and the test image happens to be a multiple of 4 pixels wide).

Comment: @Jongware Rolled back to version 1. Thank you